# How do I check what networks devices are being used to connect to a website?

Tags: networking, routing, traceroute

The question is pretty straightforward.. So, when I connect to www.google.com for example, is there a command for me to identify the network devices between my computer and the website?

If I use `traceroute google.com`, I can manually identify the devices used by checking their IP against `netstat -R` and see what device belongs to my own network. But I was wondering if there's something more explicit/specific/straightforwad for this task.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, "see what is a network device"? Every device you see in `traceroute` is _by definition_ a network device (a router, to be specific).

Comment: Sorry, I meant I can see what devices belong to my network

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get you right, but don't you see if the device is in your network by their IP's? I mean every device within you network should have an ip like 192.168.x.x.

If you request "google.com" in your browser your computer will contact your dns-server (say it does this by sending a request to the router). When the IP is returned, the router will look in its IP-Tables and send the request to the next hop which is outside of your network.

As long as you didn't setup something special in your network.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering what's the best option to see which ones are being used

Comment: My other comment is very incomplete, I tried editing it without success. So:

Yes, looking at the ip is one way, and I'd use 'traceroute' for that. But I was wondering what's the best option to see which devices are being used, other than ip's and 'traceroute'. A command that maybe showed the device's names for example